# Trying to wrap text within merged cells with openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

[image]I am having trouble wrapping the text within merged cells. The top header is what I want, but my code is giving me the bottom header. Does anyone know what I am missing here?

```
worksheet.cell(row = 1, column = 6).value = 'text to be wrapped'
worksheet.merge_cells('F1:I1')
worksheet['F1'].alignment = Alignment(vertical = "top", horizontal = "center", wrap_text = True)
```

Comment: Looks fine. The text you have is unlikely to wrap given the width of the 4 merged cells (dependant on other factors like column width and font). You can of course check that wrapping and the other setting have been applied to the cell. What were you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: @moken I updated my question to show what I am trying to do versus what my code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the code works and you should be able to see that from checking the Ribbon Home tab, alignment section and/or the cell format settings (right click 'Format Cells' --> Alignment Tab).

From your image it does seem that the alignment is not being applied, if so this seems parculiar to your install. I'd suggest you double check you are looking at the right work Book/Sheet and also to be sure that your Openpyxl version is the latest release.

If it helps;
Since the setting of the cell alignment params may not be apparent for default sizing, notwithstanding the example screen shot has resized row, columns and font, the code below includes setting these parameters similar to the example screenshot
The code creates a new Work Book/Sheet but obviously these setting can be applied to existing worksheets.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment, Font, PatternFill

### Set Font
font_style = Font(
   name="Calibri",
   b=True,
   color="000000",
   sz=20.0,
)
### Fill Colour
fuchsia_fill = PatternFill(start_color="F4B084", end_color="F4B084", fill_type ="solid")

### Create Work Book & Sheet
wb = Workbook()
worksheet = wb.active

### Add Text to the top left cell
worksheet.cell(row=1, column=6).value = 'Registration Renewals Report for May 2023'
### Merge top left cell with the next 3 cells
worksheet.merge_cells('F1:I1')
### Set column and row sizing
worksheet.column_dimensions['F'].width = 18
worksheet.column_dimensions['I'].width = 16
worksheet.row_dimensions[1].height = 52
### Apply the font and alignment and fill to the top left cell
topleftcell = worksheet['F1']
topleftcell.font = font_style
topleftcell.alignment = Alignment(vertical="top", horizontal="center", wrap_text=True)
topleftcell.fill = fuchsia_fill

### Save workbook
wb.save('foo.xlsx')
```

You should expect to get the header like this
[image: Example Screenshot]